# How can I organize QA documentation within an Agile environment

Tags: documentation, agile, development-process, quality-assurance

In Agile we favour immediate communication over documentation.
However, in QA we still have a need and desire to document the process to provide structure and guidance.
What high-level structure in our documentation would accommodate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've introduced the following structure which includes a section that reflects the Agile Testing Quadrants for Unit, Integrated, Performance and Exploratory testing.
Each link goes a detail page for that area which outlines what is being done for our company in that area.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

We have daily builds, Below are some of the lessons that worked for us

- (Knowledge Part) - Documented notes (critical discussions, one-liners - running notes are usually captured and shared after design discussions, MOM etc..). This is a quick reference used during testing, preparing test scenarios. We usually shared test queries, SQL queries written during testing in a shared folder.
- (Quick Coffee Discussions) Quick stand up for status and peer discussions and conversations while sharing bugs/discussions around them
- (Test Case Management) - Test cases were written/reviewed/shared via TCM
- (Track Discussions) We use slack for conversations. All project discussions are saved her, Discussions / Decisions not captured in documents are often referred back to discussions
- (With Remote Teams) slack works well even with remote team setup
- Common team folder to share utilities, tools developed, clean up scripts. Consolidated mail during weekends on summary/weekly status calls across teams/bug stats

Comment: Nice.  Plus one.  Perhaps a one-liner summary would be "pay attention to Documentation (where, what) and Communicatrion (who, how)".

Answer (score 1):

- Its depend on your organization how they distribute responsibilities as test team member in scrum/agile.

In SCRUM good documentation cover::

- User Stories, Test Case, Test Data.
- Automation regression testing env setup process details & how to run them.
- Test process documents & User manual update.
- No. of test cases in the sprint, pass vs failed no. test cases in acceptance criteria.